# Inner behavior of <a> element

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have a question about `<a>` tag. There is a difference between behaviors of this element that I have to defeat.

I have an url:

```
<a onclick="return Tms.Utils.Window.OpenOrFocus('#detector/14046-1', 'DT14046-1');"
   href="#detector/14046-1"
   id="ttQSearchHref">DT14046-1</a>
```

that I geneterate by this code:

```
var divEl = document.createElement("div");
divEl.innerHTML = Ext.String.format('<a id="ttQSearchHref" href="{0}" onclick="return Tms.Utils.Window.OpenOrFocus(\'{0}\', \'{1}\');">{1}</a>', Ext.htmlEncode(url), Ext.htmlEncode(name));
document.body.appendChild(divEl);               
//var a = document.getElementById('ttQSearchHref');         
//a.click();
//document.body.removeChild(divEl);
```

If I click on this link by mouse, it is opened in a new window as a tab in Chrome(v. 23, all browsers go the same way) and it is the behavior that is suitable for me. But, if I invoke click method in my code, it is opened in the a new popup window. I'm a little confused. Why if I invoke a click method is it processed as a popup, but when just click on it, it has different behaior?

```
OpenOrFocus: function(url, name) {
    if (!window.popups)
        window.popups = {};

    if (window.popups[name]) {
        window.popups[name].close();
    }

    window.popups[name] = window.open(url, name);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the behavior of the `A` element, but everything to do with the implementation of `Tms.Utils.Window.OpenOrFocus` and how it deals with popupblockers (which will kick in if you try to do `el.click()` from code not initiated by the user.

Comment: Thank you Sean Kinsey for your answer. I use window.open function for opening a new window. But the main secret for me is why when user click on the link a new tab not a popup is opened. Did I understand you corrent that the behavier depends on who is the trigger of an anction, right? If a user, so browser does less restrictions. There can I read about these diferences?

Comment: Unfortunately all of this is not documented anywhere as browsers try to 'optimize' this differently - some open new windows, some new tabs..